# how to use java to query LDAP's ROOTDSE

Tags: java, ldap

in c#, only two line need to achieve this:

```
        DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/RootDSE", dnsDomainName));
        string configurationNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["configurationNamingContext"][0].ToString();
```

how to do this in java world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out by using Spring LDAP, the LDAP URL cannot add RootDSE postfix:
LDAP://{domain name}, then use wildcard search:

```
    LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource);
    template.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
    String returnedAtts[] = { "configurationNamingContext" };
    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE,0,0,returnedAtts,false,false);

    LikeFilter  filter = new LikeFilter ("objectClass", "*");
    List<String> result = template.search("", filter.encode(), controls, new AttributesMapper<String>() {
        public String mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs)
                throws NamingException {
                return attrs.get("configurationNamingContext").get().toString();
             }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some of the extra boilerplate when using the Spring LDAP builder and a Java 8 lambda expression:

```
        List<String> result = ldapTemplate.search(query()
                    .searchScope(SearchScope.OBJECT)
                    .where("objectclass").isPresent(),
            (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs ->
                    attrs.get("configurationNamingContext").get().toString());
```

You'll also need this import:

```
import static org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQueryBuilder.*;
```